# Pauli matrices using summation notation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is there any way to write the Pauli matrices:
$$\sigma_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\sigma_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix},\sigma_3=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
(more precisely the component $(\sigma_k)_{ij}$)  **concisely** in summation notation?

Comment: More on Pauli matrices: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21595/2451

Comment: What do you mean by "summation notation"?

Comment: @DanielSank Einstein summation notation e.g. $(\vec a\times \vec b)_i=\varepsilon_{ijk} a_jb_k$

Comment: Well, it's true that $[\sigma_a, \sigma_b] = 2 i \varepsilon_{abc} \sigma_c$ and that $\{\sigma_a, \sigma_b \} = 2 \delta_{ab} I$. For all I know the Pauli matrices are uniquely determined by those properties and the fact that they're Hermitian, or something.

Comment: Those conditions are not enough to uniquely determine the Pauli matrices, because they are all left invariant by a unitary basis change $\sigma^a \mapsto P\sigma^a P^†$. To determine them uniquely you must additionally demand that $\sigma^3$ is diagonal.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Requiring $\sigma^3$ to be diagonal is still not enough to uniquely determine the Pauli matrices because you can still make transformations of the form $P = \exp(i\theta \sigma^3/2)$. To finally nail things down you have to require that $\sigma^2$ is imaginary or $\sigma^1$ is real or something like that.

Since there doesn't seem to be anything very special about the Pauli matrices themselves, I suspect there is no special notation like the question is looking for.